# Run a tutorial in Visual Studio - What kind of "New Project"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to run the first code in this tutorial with Visual Studio:

http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial_086c

As I am not very experienced with Visual Studio, i don't know what kind of project i should open (win32 console application?) und which settings i should have to run the code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create an empty (C++) project, add a source file (`main.cpp`), and then copy that code in.  However, you will also need to:

1. Download their header files and library and note where you save them.
2. Right click you project and choose "Properties".
3. Navigate to "C/C++ -> General".
4. Add the location of their header files to the "Additional Include Directories" area.
5. Navigate to "Linker -> General".
6. Add the location of their libraries (.lib files) to the "Additional Library Directories" area.
7. Navigate to "Linker -> Input".
8. Add the name(s) of their libraries that you need to link in to the "Additional Dependencies" area.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! But I still have 4 errors:
1. Can not open "vlc/libvlc.h" (line 3)
2. This Declaration has no type specifier (line 5, column 31) "("
3. ")" expected (line 5, column 51) "*excp"
4. ";" expected (line 5, column 58) "{"

Comment: @user1106770: see #4.  The compiler is telling you that it cannot find your header file.  Note that you have `"vlc/libvlc.h"`.  Try changing that to `"libvlc.h"`

Comment: Thank you, that solved error 1. But I still have 3 errors in line 5, at "(", "*" and "{"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  This was enough to get my libVLC code work with OpenCV in Visual Studio.  I did have to make my code and solution compatible with 32 bit, in case others may have similar problems.  I ended up just creating a new 32 bit solution from scratch and just copied my C++ code.